# Using Cast in Substring index

Tags: mysql, casting, substring

I'm trying to convert old_email and new_email into different variables so I can attach a few extra conditions to my query. Example-  'old_email like '%@%''.

```
    SELECT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`full_message` ,'",', 10),'"',-1) as old_email
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`full_message` ,'",', 19),'"',-1) as new_email
    from log.
```

I know I should use cast to convert it to a varchar but the syntax is proving challenging.

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SUBSTRING_INDEX already returns a string type so you don't have to CAST it to a VARCHAR or CHAR type.

You can use a delivered table to filter out old_email column like this.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (

   SELECT
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`full_message` ,'",', 10),'"',-1) as old_email
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`full_message` ,'",', 19),'"',-1) as new_email
    from log.
) 
 AS log_parsed
WHERE
 log_parsed.old_email LIKE '%@%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much Raymond - i didn't about running a query inside another one.